# WebView show Animated GIF on emulator and show static image on real device

Tags: android, webview

I have Activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layerType="software"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
        webView.loadUrl("http://gifok.net/images/2018/05/10/1212.gif");
    }
}
```

When I start this app on emulator - I see animated GIF But When I start this app on my Device - I see static image without animate. Why?

Comment: Are your device and the emulator on the same api version >

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue on Android 7.0 onwards devices with chrome version 66+.

As suggested in https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=849565#c4  removing  android:layerType="software" worked for me.